# how do I stretch a noise texture?

Tags: materials

Very new with blender so please be gentle. I have a material with a noise texture as input. I would like to stretch a material on a cube without without changing the size of the cube. This desired image is achieved when I change the cube size directly but obviously want to do without changing physical dimensions:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

just use mapping + texture coordinate node and increase the scale value of that axis you wanna stretch to a high number.

Comment: thanks! I figured it was something simple like. New to materials system and just couldn't find it.